# Trigger Republish button using spfx extension while on edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I am trying to manually trigger the republish event while editing the SharePoint page using spfx extension as below  . but there is a error in ***savePage*** api . is there way to do it ?

[image]

```js
 const publish = async() => {
            const canvasAPI = `${context.absoluteUrl}/_api/sitepages/pages(${context.spfxContex.pageContext.listItem.id})`;
            const _data = await context.spfxContex.spHttpClient.get(canvasAPI, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
            if(_data.ok) {
              const reslut = await _data.json();
              if(reslut) {
                const canvas = JSON.parse(reslut.CanvasContent1);
                console.log(canvas);
                const sptOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
                  body: `{"_metadata": {"type": "SP.Publishing.SitePage"}, "CanvasContent1": ${JSON.stringify(canvas)}}`
                }
        
                const restApi2 = `${context.absoluteUrl}/_api/sitepages/pages(${context.spfxContex.pageContext.listItem.id})/checkout`;
                const response1 = await context.spfxContex.spHttpClient.post(restApi2, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {});
        
                const restApi = `${context.absoluteUrl}/_api/sitepages/pages(${context.spfxContex.pageContext.listItem.id})/SavePage`;
                const response = await context.spfxContex.spHttpClient.post(restApi, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, sptOpts);
                console.log(response);
              }
            }
          }
```

***/savePage*** api error

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException",  "message":"There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SitePageFieldsData. End element 'CanvasContent1' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''."}}
```

Comment: Hi @InfoAsith,
I was facing the same issue. Any update on this error?

Answer (score 0):

Set `IsRequired = false`, e.g.:

```
[DataMember(Name = "CanvasContent1", IsRequired = false)]
```

**MSDN Source**: [`DataMemberAttribute.IsRequired` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that instructs the serialization engine that the
> member must be present when reading or deserializing.